# RobotFrameWork: How to click an element that's only sometimes presented

Tags: robotframework

So there's a website and sometimes an element gets in the way, a question of a pop-up.

I'd like to click that element and get rid of the pop-up.

But if the pop-up (with the element) is not presented, i'd like to continue the test as well. without any distrubances.

So what's the best way to handle this?

You cant just say:

```
Click Element  newBtn LightGray noIcon
```

Because you don't know if it's there.

Answer (score 2):

Check is the element present, and click only on true; use [`Run Keyword And Return Status`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) in combination with [`Element Should Be Visible`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Element%20Should%20Be%20Visible):

```
${is visible}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    your_locator
Run Keyword If    ${is visible}    Click Element   your_locator
```

If it takes some time for the element to appear, you could use [Wait Until Element Is Visible](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Visible) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify the present of a locator, you must use the WAIT UNTIL PAGE CONTAINS ELEMENT with it's timeout argument. We must allow the DOM or web page to finish loading (a few seconds) before we can start verify on the current page.

```
 # *you click a link here....*
${check_popup}=  Run Keyword and Return Status   Wait Until Page Contains Element    locator    6s
 Run Keyword If      ${check_popup} == 'True'     Click Element  locator
```

If you notice about, the timeout argument is optional and it has a default value, but I change it to 6 seconds. If your web page is loading slowly due to performance or others, then you need to increase the timeout time. Try not to use ELEMENT SHOULD BE VISIBLE because this keyword will fail if the pop-up / page or DOM is not completely loaded yet.

Comment: If the element is not present `Wait Until Page Contains Element` will simply failed - and so will the test case; it does not return true/false.

Comment: Yes it will fail if the element is not present. But my concern here is we should wait the DOM page to be ready or loaded properly before we can start verify on the page, that's why this keyword `Wait Until Page Contains Element` comes in handy since it has a default waiting timeout of 5-10 seconds. But if we use the `Element should be Visible`, and at the same time the page or DOM still loading, then the run will fail because the element just not available yet. So it fails before it can verify the present of the element.

Comment: > "we should wait the DOM page to be ready" - this is the purpose of all `Wait Until ...` keywords in SeleniumLibrary. The thing is OP's question is "click an element that's only sometimes present" - there are occasions where it is not; and then - the case will fail in this combo, just because in this run it did not appear.

Comment: Okay, I will add more explanation in my answer. it needs a `Run Keyword and Return Status` as you already give. But my solution is to use it with `Wait Until Page Contains Element`, thanks.

Comment: Ok, and to my main point then - how it will be different from the other answer - "If it takes some time for the element to appear, you could use Wait Until Element Is Visible instead." :)

Comment: Yes, `Wait Until Element Is Visible` is good to use too other than `Wait Until Page Contains Element`.  It's just a personal preference :)